# Showing Error red .add() when adding Data into ArrayList

Tags: java, android, oop, arraylist, android-recyclerview

When I am trying to add Data in arraylist(`listModels`) in another class which is `FetchStockApi` it is showing red Error .add()(Cannot resolve symbol 'add'). But If I don't use `FetchStockApi`, and without taking it's instance, Add stuff in some ArrayList Created in MainActivity and use it for adapter it works and program works.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText suggestSearch;
RecyclerView suggestionList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    suggestSearch = findViewById(R.id.searchBar);
    suggestionList = findViewById(R.id.suggestionList);

    // FetchStockApi Class
    FetchStockApi fetchStockApi = new FetchStockApi();

    // Adapter
    suggestListAdapter adapter = new suggestListAdapter();
    adapter.setStringArrayList(fetchStockApi.listModels);

    suggestionList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    suggestionList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

FetchStockApi.java

```
package com.example.stockapipractice2;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FetchStockApi {

ArrayList<suggestListModel> listModels = new ArrayList<>();
String stockName = "Nifty 50";
String stockSymbol = "NFTY";
String exchange = "NSI";
String type = "Index";
suggestListModel SuggestListModel = new suggestListModel(stockName, stockSymbol,exchange,type);
listModels.add(SuggestListModel);
// This above add is showing the Error
}
```

I just want to add Data in FetchStockApi and later use it in MainActivity for Recycler View adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 separate instances of `listModels`. One in `MainActivity` and one in `FetchStockApi`. This is why making changes to the instance in `FetchStockApi` has no effect on the instance in `MainActivity`.

If you want to share the same instance, then you need to pass a reference of the instance you create in `MainActivity` to `FetchStockApi` so that it can manipulate that instance.

---

You can pass the `listModels` reference to `FetchStockApi` when you instantiate it. To do this, create a constructor for `FetchStockApi` like this:

```
public FetchStockApi(List<suggestListModel> listModels) {
    this.listModels = listModels;
}
```

Also change the declaration of `listModels` in `FetchStockApi` to this:

```
List<suggestListModel> listModels;
```

It will get initialized in the constructor.

Now you need to pass a reference to `listModels` from `MainActivity` to `FetchStockApi` when it gets constructed. Change `MainActivity` to instantiate `FetchStockApi` like this:

```
FetchStockApi fetchStockApi = new FetchStockApi(listModels);
```

Now `FetchStockApi` can manipulate the same instance of `listModels` that `MainActivity` is using and that `MainActivity` has passed to the `ListAdapter`.

The only problem you now have is that after `FetchStockApi` has made changes to `listModels`, you need to somehow inform the `ListView` that the underlying data has changed, so that it can redraw the `ListView`. You could create an interface and have `MainActivity` implement this interface and have `FetchStockApi` call a method on that interface after it makes changes to `listModels`, but it is easier (although not as elegant) to just declare a public method in `MainActivity` like this:

```
void notifyListModelsChanged() {
    suggestionList.notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

then add a member variable that will hold a reference to `MainActivity` to `FetchStockApi` like this:

```
MainActivity mainActivity;
```

then add a reference to `MainActivity` in the `FetchStockApi` constructor, like this:

```
public FetchStockApi(List<suggestListModel> listModels, MainActivity mainActivity;) {
    this.listModels = listModels;
    this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
}
```

then pass a reference to `MainActivity` to `FetchStockApi` in the constructor, like this:

```
FetchStockApi fetchStockApi = new FetchStockApi(listModels, this);
```

and have `FetchStockApi` call this method after it updates `listModels`, like this:

```
mainActivity.notifyListModelsChanged();
```

Comment: Eventhough, if I delete the code                                           ArrayList<suggestListModel> listModels = new ArrayList<>();
//        String stockName = "Nifty 50";
//        String stockSymbol = "NFTY";
//        String exchange = "NSI";
//        String type = "Index";
//        suggestListModel SuggestListModel = new suggestListModel(stockName, stockSymbol,exchange,type);
//        listModels.add(SuggestListModel);`  in Main Activity. listModels.add(SuggestModel) still doesn't work in FetchStockAPI class

Comment: `listModels.add(SuggestModel)` in `FetchStockApi` adds an entry to `listModels` in the instance of `FetchStockApi`. But this doesn't have anything to do with the data that is displayed in `MainActivity`. The data that is displayed in `MainActivity` is the instance of `listModels` in `MainActivity` that is passed to the adapter like this: `adapter.setStringArrayList(listModels);`

Comment: How is `FetchStockApi` instantiated? I don't see any code in `MainActivity` that creates an instance of `FetchStockApi` or calls any methods in it.

Comment: Okay, so what should I do so, that I can add Data into the `ArrayList in FetchBook` and use that list in `Adapter` for Recycler View. Instead of `MainActivity.` And one more thing in `FetchBook listModels.add()` add is in red color and showing error (Cannot resolve symbol 'add') and Thank you for the help so far.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the linkage between `MainActivity` and `FetchStockApi`. Then I can probably help you.

Comment: Hello sir, I have edited the question. Hope it's right now, if there are any other edits I need to make please let me know. And Sorry for late editing.